# Listening to presskey takes a lot of processor speed

Tags: python

While I'm using the code below, python takes 30% of the processor speed.
Is there a way to avoid that?

```
import keyboard  
while True:  
    try:  
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+shift+m'):  
            print('You Pressed ctrl+shift+m')
            break  
    except:
        break
```

Comment: What platform? Try using pygame/tkinter, will probably be faster.

Comment: Can anyone tag this thing properly?

Answer (score 3):

`is_pressed` always returns `True` or `False` immediately. It doesn't wait for keys to be pressed or released. Thus, your code is constantly in a loop, checking as often as it can whether those keys are pressed. Instead of `is_pressed`, use `wait`:

```
import keyboard
keyboard.wait('ctrl+shift+m')
print('You Pressed ctrl+shift+m')
```

Comment: @kostinalex If this solved your problem, please mark it as accepted with the check mark button.

Answer (score 0):

Using keyboard.wait and while loop works well:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    keyboard.wait('ctrl+shift+m')
    print('You Pressed ctrl+shift+m')
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is spinning in a busy loop.

Add a call to `time.sleep(0.1)` at the beginning of the while loop.
That will check for keypresses approximately 10x per second, and sleep the rest of the time.

Comment: If the user presses and releases the key combination too quickly, this will miss it.